# Error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.1

**ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PicsController#show**

Couldn't find Pic with 'id'=1

Extracted source (around line #34):

```
  def find_pic
    @pic = Pic.find(params[:id])
  end
```

I cant resolve the error.

My **pics_controller.rb**  is as follows.

```
class PicsController < ApplicationController

      before_action :find_pic, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      def index   
      end
      def show
      end   
      def new
        @pic = Pic.new
      end 
      def create
        @pic = current_user.pics.build(pic_params)
        if @pic.save
          redirect_to @pic,notice: "Yesss! It was posted!"
        else
          render 'new'
        end
      end
      private   
       def pic_params
        params.require(:pic).permit(:title, :description)
      end
      def find_pic
        @pic = Pic.find(params[:id]).permit(:title) rescue nil
      end
    end
```

My **show.html.haml**

```
%h1= @pic.title
%p= @pic.description

= link_to "Back", root_path
```

Update: I ran `rake routes` and here is the output.

```
$ rake routes
  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern              Controller#Action
    pics GET    /pics(.:format)          pics#index
         POST   /pics(.:format)          pics#create
 new_pic GET    /pics/new(.:format)      pics#new
edit_pic GET    /pics/:id/edit(.:format) pics#edit
     pic GET    /pics/:id(.:format)      pics#show
         PATCH  /pics/:id(.:format)      pics#update
         PUT    /pics/:id(.:format)      pics#update
         DELETE /pics/:id(.:format)      pics#destroy
    root GET    /                        pics#index
```

Comment: there is not record in `pics` table

Comment: If you open the console and try Pic.find(1), is there a record with that id?

Comment: Do not post pictures in your questions. Instead, cut and paste the relevant text. Some other person with he same problem may come across this question later, but if your image host deletes the image, the question isn't going to make sense anymore.

Comment: No still showing Error -> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Pic with 'id'=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `@pic = Pic.find(params[:id])` that should be enough.

```
%h1= @pic.title if @pic.present?
%p= @pic.description if @pic.present?

= link_to "Back", root_path
```

try to rescue the error, if no pic is present.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused with this `.permit` on an object and `rescue nil` thing. Why it's required?

> As far as I know `.permit` is allowed only on `ActionController::Parameters`, [more details](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permitted-3D)

So maybe you have to rewrite that `find_pic`:

```
def find_pic
  @pic = Pic.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: without adding that permit it is coming up with another error.

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PicsController#show